# REST form validation in symfony 2 - how to test post

Tags: validation, rest, symfony

The form is never valid, but `$form->getErrors()` gives no error.
Since its gonna be a REST API test it with DEV HTTP client

test data is

**Header:**
`Content-Type:application/json`

**Body:**
`{"username":"sad","password":"123","email":"asdsads@fgfdg.com"}`

I don't have any validation.yml file

Is there any any method to find out whats going wrong (error Message)?

```
public function postUserAction(Request $request)
{

    return $this->processForm(new User(),$request);
}

private function processForm(User $user, Request $request )
{


    $form = $this->createForm(new UserType(), $user);
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isValid()) {

         return array('form' => 'valid');
    }

    return \FOS\RestBundle\View\View::create($form->getErrors(),400);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After a little debug:
isValid() checks form several things eg if the form has been submitted. It wasnt, so i changed to

```
...
        $form = $this->createForm(new UserType(), $user);
        //$form->handleRequest($request);
        $form->submit($request);

        if ($form->isValid()) {
...
```

now its valid.

Comment: You may be able to still use handleRequest() if you add some options into the optional third parameter to createForm with the method, like array("method" => "POST").  It was the only way I was able to get the form to submit using handleRequest().  I went the extra mile to get handleRequest() to work because submit() called with a $request as an argument is deprecated starting in symfony 2.3 and apparently will be gone in 3.0.

Answer (score 1):

When debugging a form validation,

use `$form->getErrorsAsString()` instead of `$form->getErrors()`.

(*which will run in to deep level including the form children.*)

Comment: thank you. It looks like there is no error: "form":"username:\n    No errors\npassword:\n    No errors\nemail:\n    No errors\n", but the form is still inValid...

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

```
$form = $this->createForm(new UserType(), $user);
$jsonData = json_decode($request->getContent(), true); // "true" to get an associative array

if ('POST' === $request->getMethod()) {
    $form->bind($jsonData);
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am late to reply to this one but, all answers are wrong. `submit` should be avoided and use `handleRequest` instead. [Read this](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/direct_submit.html). That form was not valid with `handleRequest` because `UserType` was missing one of the next:

1. A form field was missing
2. A form field was not in appropriate format
3. In `UserType` class `getName` function should return empty string and `csrf_protection` should be disabled (IF you are using `API` approach where `form` was `not generated` from your Symfony2 project):

   ```
   public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
   {
       $resolver->setDefaults(array(
           'data_class' => 'UserApiBundle\Entity\User',
           'csrf_protection'   => false,
       ));
   }

   public function getName()
   {
       return '';
   }
   ```

   `submit` would not check for that and it is a bad approach for `POST`. You could use it for `PUT` request to update a `User` where `password` field would not be submitted for xyz reasons (ex: permissions).

   ```
   $form->submit($request, false);
   ```

It is hard to dig for `form` errors in Symfony2. You can use this function to get errors:

```
public function getErrors($form)
{
    $errors = array();
    foreach ($form as $fieldName => $formField) {
        $currentError = $formField->getErrors();

        if ($currentError->current()) {
            $current = $currentError->current();
            $errors[$fieldName] = $current->getMessage();
        }
    }

    return $errors;
}
```